# Add custom variable to page.tpl.php using custom module?

Tags: 7, theming, configuration

I found this solution here:

https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2010-12-25/add-custom-variable-to-pagetplphp

I created a module for give possibility to some users to change the background file from the UI.

In my module:

```
function office_file_upload_preprocess_page(&$vars)
{
    $vars['background'] = "BK2.jpg";
}
```

In my

> page.tpl.php

Now how can I modify permanently  after this function

```
$upload = file_save_upload('upload_item', $validators, $location, $replace = FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

the above variable to change the background?

I tried

> variable_set($vars['background'], $upload->filename)

but no luck!

This is the form

[image]

and this is the module:

https://kopy.io/kOW3s

Comment: Hey hey, your request is a little bit too broad actually. Basically you might consider 1) to create a custom config (settings) page 2) where you offer radios to choose an image and 3) then store that value into a variable, 4) to later retrieve the value inside a preprocess function 5) to pass it over to a template. There are quite a bunch of tutorials out there. And just to clarify you are using D7, are you?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment! I'm on D7 and I uploaded the form and the code of my module.
You're right I'm a bit broad but I'm actually confused: if I put my preprocess in template.php, anytime the file is called the variable will be reset to the original value, isn't it? So I put the preprocess function in the module but I'm stuck on variable_get that doesn't work :(

Comment: In your submit function you miss to actually set the variable, p.e. `variable_set('background_file', $file_id)`. By that it get's stored in the variables table where you can retrieve it with p.e. `$file_id = variable_get('background_file', NULL)`. Plus you have to ensure this happens on a per-user basis.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I remove my preproces function and add a variable_set() in my callback and...magic!!